# Slow performance on Impala query using Group By and Like

Tags: performance, hadoop, cloudera, impala

We are testing Apache Impala and have noticed that using GROUP BY and LIKE together works very slowly -- separate queries work much faster. Here are two examples:

```
# 1.37s 1.08s 1.35s

SELECT * FROM hive.default.pcopy1B where 
     (lower("by")  like '%part%' and lower("by")  like '%and%' and lower("by")  like '%the%') 
  or (lower(title) like '%part%' and lower(title) like '%and%' and lower(title) like '%the%') 
  or (lower(url)   like '%part%' and lower(url)   like '%and%' and lower(url)   like '%the%') 
  or (lower(text)  like '%part%' and lower(text)  like '%and%' and lower(text)  like '%the%') 
limit 100;
```

---

```
# 156.64s 155.63s

select "by", type, ranking, count(*) from pcopy where 
     (lower("by")  like '%part%' and lower("by")  like '%and%' and lower("by")  like '%the%') 
  or (lower(title) like '%part%' and lower(title) like '%and%' and lower(title) like '%the%') 
  or (lower(url)   like '%part%' and lower(url)   like '%and%' and lower(url)   like '%the%') 
  or (lower(text)  like '%part%' and lower(text)  like '%and%' and lower(text)  like '%the%') 
group by "by", type, ranking 
order by 4 desc limit 10;
```

Why does this issue occur, and are there any workarounds?

Comment: The two queries seem very different to me. The first just selects records and only needs one cursor, the second has to retrieve all the records and run  both a GROUP and a SORT. If there are very many records returned, this might explain the difference in time. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a basic difference between two queries.

**1st Query**

Main points:

- Only 100 rows are selected.
- As soon as process gets 100 rows which satisfies provided `WHERE` clause, it is marked as completed and 100 records will be returned.
- There will be only 1 mapper step. Number of mapper will be dependent on your data size.

**2nd Query**

Main points:

- Only 10 rows are selected.
- Even though only 10 rows are selected, the process needs to scan full data in order to generate results based on `GROUP BY` clause.
- There should be 3 mapper-reducer steps. Number of mapper-reducer on each step will dependent on data size.

  - 1st MP will read the data and apply `WHERE` clause
  - 2nd MR will be for `GROUP BY` clause.
  - 3rd MR will be for `ORDER BY` clause.

So the queries provided by you might look similar but they are totally different and solves all together different purpose.